# Why is my key binding causing a double press in my input?

Tags: python, button, bind, key-bindings

I used the master.bind function to bind the keys to my buttons in calculator. However, that now causes the first input in my calculator to be detected as a double press, but only the very initial input when I run the module. How can i stop this from happening?

This is my binding function with the some of the keys:

```
def key_bind(self, master):
        master.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.equals())
        master.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda event: self.backspace())
        master.bind("9", lambda event: self.expression(9))
        master.bind("8", lambda event: self.expression(8))
        master.bind("7", lambda event: self.expression(7))
        master.bind("6", lambda event: self.expression(6))
        master.bind("5", lambda event: self.expression(5))
        master.bind("4", lambda event: self.expression(4))
        master.bind("3", lambda event: self.expression(3))
        master.bind("2", lambda event: self.expression(2))
        master.bind("1", lambda event: self.expression(1))
```

The expected output of pressing "3" on my keyboard is of course 3. But when i first open the calculator and press a number like "3", it shows 33 instead.